# Apache Rewrite to Nginx Rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I have the following apache rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^id/([^/\.]+)$ item.php?id=$1 [L]
```

and I need to be able to use it with Nginx. It is meant to so that someone can go to http://mysite.com/id/10 and instead of having to be go http://mysite.com/item.php?id=10.
Can anyone help me convert it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
 rewrite ^/id/([^/\.]+)$ /item.php?id=$1 last;
```

Answer (score 8):

you mean like this:

```
rewrite ^/id/([0-9]+)/?$ /item.php?id=$1 last;
```

Comment: +1 for using only digits and avoiding errors like letters as ID

Comment: It could be better but is not correct answer to the question. The original rule was not matching only digits.